# limiting a html text area to mx length?

Tags: html

i have a html text area in a form like so:

```
<form>
<input type="textarea" maxlength="20">
</form>
```

i have limited the number of characters to 20, however users can still use excessive spacing and breaks in between character in the form text area.

Basically i have a button in the lower right corner of the text area the whole purpose of me limiting the character length is so the text doesn't overflow and go over the button.

I dont want to use padding or overflow: hidden because this si not what im trying to do. but is there a way i can limit the number of characters in the text area including spacing?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

`<textarea name='text' style="max-width:20px;" placeholder='write text here'></textarea>`
and u should check the `rows` and `cols` attributes of the `<textarea>` tag